# Angular CLI Error

Tags: angular

If I want to make ng serve, I get this error :

> ERROR in TypeError: Cannot read property 'provide' of undefined
>       at C:\Users\Samir\Documents\AngularProjects\test\angular_website\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:150:14
>       at Array.reduce (native)
>       at _collectRoutes (C:\Users\Samir\Documents\AngularProjects\test\angular_website\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:149:22)
>       at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (C:\Users\Samir\Documents\AngularProjects\test\angular_website\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:113:8)
>       at Object.listLazyRoutesOfModule (C:\Users\Samir\Documents\AngularProjects\test\angular_website\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:53:22)
>       at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (C:\Users\Samir\Documents\AngularProjects\test\angular_website\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.js:91:39)
>       at AotPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (C:\Users\Samir\Documents\AngularProjects\test\angular_website\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:207:44)
>       at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (C:\Users\Samir\Documents\AngularProjects\test\angular_website\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:443:24)

I also deleted all node_modules and installed the newest version of the cli,
but this is not my code. Has someone a solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

This error is usually comming from the import statement of a service. You should try importing the service using the exact path of the service itself instead of using an index.ts file that exports the service.

**Instead of**

Using index.ts file with:

```
export * from './services/myservice.service';
```

and then in the module/component that provides that service you are writing the import to the index.ts file like that:

```
import {MyService} from './services';
```

**Try this**

Try to import the service using the relative path to the service itself:

```
import {myService} from './services/myservice.service';
```

Comment: are you sure? this are onyl ng_modules and it isn't code from me

Comment: This is the error that I got and what solved it for me. Do you have any services in your app?

Comment: if you have no code than I will recomand that you try upgrading yout angular-cli.
Follow these instructions: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli

Comment: This worked for me. I want to know why there is a difference between the 2 methods of importing. Logically they should be the same. This seems like a bug in angular.

Answer (score 0):

In `app.module.ts`, are you using any import like this:

```
import MyImport from 'myPath';
```

?
If yes, you need change your `MyImport.ts` to be imported like this:

```
import { MyImport } from 'myPath';
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to @Injectable(). Previous to Angular 11, @Injectable needs to be added for injecting services within a service.

In Angular 11 and future releases, @Injectable() needs to be added to all the defined services.